# What does it mean to 'move' a file into include path list?

Tags: php, include-path

In the book Zend Framework, a Beginner's guide; it says:

*The contents of the `library/` directory should be moved to a location in your PHP “include
path” list.*

I don't get it. Doesn't include path hold values that reference a certain directory in a certain location. Is that what it means? or do I litterally have to move the folder to a place that is already mentioned in "include path"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PHP's [`include_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) serves the same purpose as the system's PATH environment variable:

> "It defines a list of directories to search through when looking for a command to execute." ([Bob Rankin](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-environment-variables.html), 2011).

As the previous comment by andre matos indicated, you can either copy the library directory to your system's PHP include_path directory or you can set the PHP path configuration directive, 'include_path', in your php.ini file to include the library directory as a directory for PHP to search through.

Regardless of which way you choose, you need to know your system's PHP include_path directory. To find your system's PHP include_path directory, you can either do:

```
% php -i | grep include_path # assuming you are on Linux
```

-or, create a file, e.g., 'phpinfo.php', and add the following php code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and run the file through PHP,

```
% php phpinfo.php | grep include_path
```

-or, alternatively, add the file e.g., 'phpinfo.php', to a directory your web server knows about, and open it as a url in a web browser and search for 'include_path.'

For example, my system's PHP include_path is at: `/usr/lib64/php`

Although the easiest way is arguably to just copy the library directory to your system's PHP include_path directory (e.g., /usr/lib64/php), it is also equivalently easy to set the PHP path configuration directive 'include_path' in your system's php.ini file.

To set the PHP path configuration directive 'include_path' in your system's php.ini file, open the file and locate the 'include_path' path configuration directive under the 'Paths and Directories' section. It should look something like this:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
```

Remove the ';' from the PHP 'include_path' path configuration directive for your operating system.

e.g., If you are on Linux, it should look like this:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
```

Then set the PHP 'include_path' path configuration directive to the library directory, as a directory for PHP to search through.

e.g., I downloaded the ZendFramework to

`/usr/src/done/ZendFramework-1.11.4-minimal/`

Therefore, I must set the PHP 'include_path' configuration directive to include the library directory within the ZendFramework directory, like this:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/src/done/ZendFramework-1.11.4-minimal/library"
```

The 'Paths and Directories' section in the system's php.ini file, should now look like this:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
include_path = ".:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/src/done/ZendFramework-1.11.4-minimal/library"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
```

Let me explain the directories I added to the PHP 'include_path' configuration directive in the php.ini file (shown above):

The '.' is the current directory, the '/usr/lib64/php' is the system's PHP include_path directory, and the '/usr/src/done/ZendFramework-1.11.4-minimal/library' is the path to the library directory in the ZendFramework directory. Note that each directory listed in the PHP 'include_path' configuration directive must be separated by a ':' (same as the directories listed in the system's PATH environment variable).

After you have added your list of directories to the PHP 'include_path" configuration directive in the php.ini file, you must restart your web server to save the changes to PHP.

e.g., `% sudo apachectl restart # assumes you are using Apache as your web server`

Hope this helps,

//. Elliot

Answer (score 1):

Well... You can do both.

Add an include path to your `php.ini` (search for something like `include_path`)

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = ".;C:\PHP\pear;C:\PHP\otherfolder"
```

Or move the folder to some path already included (that you will know which are after performing the previous search on `php.ini`).

When you do something like:

```
<?php include 'file.php'; ?>
```

If the file is not in the same directory (.) as the script you're executing php will look in the include paths defined on php.ini.