# Putting PEARs php_dir into include_path in php.ini

Tags: pear, php

I'm unsure of how to alter my php.ini file according to the instructions on the PEAR website

It says "In every case, PEAR's php_dir should be in the include path. If not, add it in your system's php.ini."

On my system(Mac 10.6.6), this is PEAR's php dir

```
/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/share/pear
```

On my system, this is the php.ini include path

```
.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php
```

What should the resulting path look like in my php.ini?  Do I delete the current path and replace it with PEAR's php dir path? or do I somehow integrate the two?

Thanks for your help.  If you can please type out the whole path as it should be. I'm not very experienced ...

Comment: Why not have a look at the documentation before asking? -> http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you may have already discovered, you need to set the PHP path configuration directive, 'include_path', in your system's php.ini file to:

```
include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php:/Users/michaelmitchell/pear/share/pear"
```

For a more detailed explanation of how to set the PHP path configuration directive, 'include_path', in your system's php.ini file, please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648358/what-does-it-mean-to-move-a-file-into-include-path-list/5672408#5672408) to the question [What does it mean to 'move' a file into include path list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5648358/679795)

Hope this helps,

//. Elliot

Answer (score 1):

problem solved. Just separate the two paths with colon (on Linux) or semicolon on Windows

ch2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path