# Using Pear's PHP codesniffer with MAMP Pro on mac

Tags: php, macos, pear, mamp, phpcodesniffer

I’d like to ask for some help getting Pear’s PHP Code Sniffer set up properly.

I’m using MAMP pro 2.0.5 on a Mac PB 10.7.4 with PHP 5.3.6.
I do have Pear installed and can run pear commands, when I installed the PHP_CodeSniffer channel I didn’t get any errors but I can’t trigger any commands.

Here is a screen shot of my command line:
https://skitch.com/stephanief0042/etuck/alohamediaworks-bash-100x40

I was able to reference this post: 
[Putting PEARs php_dir into include_path in php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831136/putting-pears-php-dir-into-include-path-in-php-ini)

But my include path seems correct:
include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear"

When I traced the path to the PHPCS install I found it’s executable file on this path: Users/alohamediaworks/pear/bin/phpcs

I’m not sure if i’m one symlink from being able to use this or not, any help or suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PEAR will install bin files like PHPCS into a configurable location. You can see this location by running `pear config-show | grep bin_dir`.

The value here is probably currently `/Users/alohamediaworks/pear/bin`

You might want to just set it to `/Applications/MAMP/bin` or somewhere local on your Mac, like `/usr/local/bin`.

Before you do this, it is worth uninstalling PHP_CodeSniffer, and also checking that PEAR knows where PHP is by running `pear config-show | grep php_bin`.

I'll assume both values need changing:

```
pear uninstall PHP_CodeSniffer
pear config-set bin_dir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin
pear config-set bin_dir /Applications/MAMP/bin
pear install PHP_CodeSniffer
```

(check that the paths are valid first and that you don't have friendlier symlink versions)

You need the php_bin to be correct because PEAR will change the #! line of all bin files (like phpcs) on install to point to your PHP executable. The bin_dir is important to ensure bin files are placed into a directory that is in your path. Uninstalling PHP_CodeSniffer is required so old files are not left around (PEAR wont move them).

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for the help, the configs you suggested were an exact match, but when I attempted the config resets I got messages of success but still show a "command not found". here is a screen cap of my command line, if you have any other suggestions I'm all ears. [link]https://skitch.com/stephanief0042/etsh7/alohamediaworks-bash-117x29

Comment: I'm also not sure how to check for symlinks. I know I've used some to set up Drush but I think thats all. Thanks again.

Comment: another note, after making the changes above, my pear install is still running fine, and when I run "pear list-channels" Code sniffer, which is installed with no errors is not listed.

Comment: Sorry, I think I got the bin_dir wrong in my answer. Try `pear config-set bin_dir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin`. You may also want to run `echo $PATH` to make sure that directory is listed in your PATH. You'll also need to reinstall PHP_CodeSniffer after this change.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! I can now use the phpcs -h command and see the screen I expect (what the pear site says I should see).
Thank you so very much for the help! :)

Comment: Hi! i'm pretty well stuck after following your command as typing phpcs -h will result in no command or directory found. on what specific folder should i fire this command? thanks!

Comment: It wont matter where you run the command, but the fact that it doesn't find the phpcs command means that phpcs is not in your path. There should be a phpcs file in the PEAR bin directory (pear config-show | grep bin_dir) that you can try running directly to ensure phpcs is installed correctly. If it is, you just need to add that directory to your PATH.