# Installing Pear's PHP CodeSniffer in MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, pear, mamp-pro

I've been attempting to install PEAR's PHP CodeSniffer for use with phpStorm and a local MAMP installation, but I can't get Terminal to recognize the `phpcs` or `phpcbf` commands - no matter what I do, I always get a 'command not found' error.

I've followed the accepted answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273255/using-pears-php-codesniffer-with-mamp-pro-on-mac) to configure PEAR and make sure it was accessing the appropriate `bin` directories for both PHP and the app config, but again, neither of the commands are recognized and I get the following error message why I try to install with `pear install PHP_CodeSniffer`:

`No releases available for package "pear.php.net/PHP_CodeSniffer"
install failed`

I'm using MAMP PRO 3.2.1 with PHP 5.4.39 on OS X 10.10.3 - is there anything that I've missed?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but have you tried using composer to install code sniffer to get phpcs and phpcbf?

Comment: Just tried to install globally with Composer...installation ran with no error messages, still can't use the commands.

Comment: You need to make sure that the global composer bin folder is accessible to your system (in windows for example, add an entry to your PATH environment variable that points to c:/path/to/composer/vendor/bin)